# order and Invoice tab is missing under sales tab magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel

if I hit this URL I got all my order but order tab is missing

http://www.website.com/index.php/admin0_tara/sales_order/index/key/6b72aec96dd9dbb2bd2121471a238316/

[image: sales tab missing]

1) From which file these tabs are created or what will be the issues that make it hidden.

Any help.

Thanks In advance.

**Update**: I used my backup to overcome this issue , because I tried my best to solve the issue and find exact cause , but failed each time .

Answer (score 0):

Go to System -> Permissions -> Roles (as Admin) and check if your role has access to the Order view.

Comment: i did this , created new one with all privileges . same Issue

Comment: can  i check sales.xml

Comment: which table is responsible for admin role do you have any idea ?

Comment: The table is called `admin_role`